# Mongoengine filter query on list embedded field based on last index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm using Mongoengine with Django.

I have an embedded field in my model. that is a list field of embedded documents.

```
import mongoengine

class OrderStatusLog(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    status_code = mongoengine.StringField()

class Order(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    incr_id = mongoengine.SequenceField()
    status = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(OrderStatusLog))
```

Now I want to filter the result on `Order` collection based on the last value in `status` field.

e.g. `Order.objects.filter(status__last__status_code="scode")`

I guess there is no such thing `__last`. I tried the approach mentioned in the docs http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#querying-lists
but didn't work.

I can solve this by looping over all the documents in the collection but thats not efficient, how can we write this query efficiently.

Comment: I think you should tag your question python so that 1/ it is listed as a python question 2/ it gets automatic syntax highlighting. (Alternatively, you may specify `<!-- language: lang-python -->` before the code block: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure MongoEngine can do that (yet). AFAIK, you'd need to use the aggregation pipeline.

In the Mongo shell, using the ['$slice'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operators:

```
db.order.aggregate([{ $project: {last_status: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $slice: [ "$status", -1 ] }, 0 ]} }}, {$match: {'last_status.status_code':"scode"}} ])
```

And in Python:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$project': {'last_status': { '$arrayElemAt': [{ '$slice': [ "$status", -1 ] }, 0 ]} }},
    {'$match': {'last_status.status_code':'scode'}}
]

agg_cursor = Order.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)

result = [ Order.objects.get(id=order['_id']) for order in agg_cursor ]
```

The trick here is that `objects.aggregate` provides a `PyMongo` cursor, not a `MongoEngine` cursor, so if you need `MongoEngine` objects, you can proceed in two steps: first filter using the aggregation framework to get the ids of matched items, then get them through a `MongoEngine` query.

This is what I do. From my tests, it had proven to be much more efficient than fetching everything and filtering in the python code.

If there is a simpler way, I'm interested to ear about it. Otherwise, this could be a feature request for MongoEngine. You may want to open an issue [there](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues).

Comment: Thanx Jerome. I tried with second one and its working.Thanx alot.